# HTML table header cannot be frozen

Tags: html, css

I apply position: sticky to table header.  When I scroll it, header will out of screen.  I need to use dynamic html code.  Because, row data is fetched from server and unknown row count.  Stack Overflow cannot have lengthly code and I simply it by "for (var key in data[0])" loop.

[image]

When I scroll, H1/H2 header will be out of screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Order Selection</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        th {
            position: sticky;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section id="dataDisplay">
</section>
 
<script>
    function disp() {
        var html = '<table>';
        html += '<thead>';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<th>' + 'H1' + '</th>';
        html += '<th>' + 'H2' + '</th>';
        html += '</tr>';
        html += '</thead>';
        html += '<tbody>';

        for (var i=1;i<=20; i++) {
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + `RA` + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + `RB` + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        }

        html += '</tbody>';
        html += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('dataDisplay').innerHTML = html;
    }
    disp();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `top: 0` to the `th` css rule [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    th {
        position: sticky;
        top:0;
    }
```

You need to specify where the headings will appear